# Excel function with the same name as cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using an add-in to Microsoft Excel called [Isoplot](http://www.bgc.org/isoplot_etc/isoplot.html), it's used for analysing and processing radiometric data for dating geological materials etc.

One of the user defined functions is intended to calculate an isotope ratio for 207Pb/206Pb for any given age, however the function has been named "Pb76", so when I go to enter `=PB76(cell reference)` I get the `#REF!` error, as Excel thinks Pb76 is a cell reference rather than a function.  How can I tell Excel that I'm referring to a User Defined function rather than a cell reference?  I've tried `="Pb76"(cell reference)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

P.S. I didn't design Isoplot and I can't edit the User Defined functions as they're password protected. This was a real oversight on behalf of the original creator!

Comment: You can write a wrap function like Func_PB76 and call it! The wrap function just call the original PB76 and nothing else (matters^^) :)

Comment: I would just give cell PB76 a named reference and reference it that way.  For example, if we gave the name 'test' to the cell PB76 we could then say =test

Comment: I'm curious how the developer of an Excel Add-in would not have the issue in the first place. Have you checked with the developer? Are your versions compatible? I noticed this note on their website: *"Isoplot 3 is not compatible with either Excel 2007 or Excel 2010. If you must use Excel 2007 or Excel 2010, request a copy Isoplot 4, which is compatible with Excel 2007/2010 only. Isoplot 4 has no more functionality than Isoplot 3.7, and somewhat less flexibility. Expect a speed penalty of up to a factor of 10 when using Excel 2007/2010."*